# Render custom content on validation error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wish to bring attention to fields which have not passed model validation. In the case of a textbox, for example, could a red asterisk be printed?

Such as: `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName)<span title="The User Name is required.">*</span>`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something simple like this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "*")
```

You need the following scripts:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: There has to be a better way that doesn't require javascript =/

Comment: Since you are working with MVC better get used to use JavaScript and jQuery